# Gelfand triples and embedding of vector-valued spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, bochner-spaces

Suppose $u\in L^2(0,T; V)$ and $u_t\in L^2(0,T;V')$, where $V\subset H\subset V'$ is a Gelfand (or Hilbert) triple (the embeddings are dense and continuous and the spaces are all Hilbert). For instance take $H^1_0\subset L^2\subset H^{-1}$. Then it is well-known that $u\in C([0,T];H)$ (see for instance Theorem 6.41 in Hunter's notes: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch6A.pdf)

What goes wrong if we take $V=H$ above (so that instead $V\subset V\subset V'$), and conclude that in fact $u\in C([0,T];V)$? I believe this is incorrect and that the issue stems from how we identify dual spaces, say $H\equiv H'$ and not $V\equiv V'$, but it's unclear exactly how things go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the triplet $V \subset V \subset V'$ you no longer have $u_t \in L^2(0,T; V')$.

In fact, denote by $I$ the embedding from $V$ to $H$. Then, the statement $u_t \in L^2(0,T;V')$ really means $(I^* u)_t \in L^2(0,T;V')$. By changing the middle space in the triplet, you change $I$ and hence, $u_t \in L^2(0,T;V')$ is no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How are you obtaining that $u_t \in L^2(0,T;V')$ implies $(I^*u)_t \in L^2(0,T;V)$?

Comment: Because this is the definition. However, the $I^*$ is typically not mentioned and, thus, confusion arises.

Comment: @gerw Would you please explain more. I don't understand what $(I*u)' \in L^2(0,T;V)$ means at all. Given $u \in L^2(0,T:V)$, $u_t =w $ is defined as the element of $L^2(0,T;V^*)$ satisfyin $\int_0^T u(t)\varphi'(t) = -\int_0^T w(t)\varphi(t)$ for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(0,T)$. 

So $u'$ belongs to $L^2(0,T;V^*)$ proper, and $I^*\colon H^* \to V^*$ does not seem to make sense to me to apply to $u$ and then take the derivative

Comment: @StopUsingFacebook: In your integral identity, the left hand side is from $V$, whereas the right-hand side is from $V'$. This is a different space! Moreover, $I^*$ is the adjoint of $I$ and this operators maps into $V'$. (There was also a prime missing in my answer. Fixed now.)

Comment: @gerw "This is a different space" Agree, but $V \subset V^*$ through the Hilbert triple so it makes sense

Comment: @StopUsingFacebook: And this is the confusing part: The embedding $V \hookrightarrow V^*$ is really $I^* I$ and, thus, depends on $H$.

Answer (score 0):

One/another problem is that in $V\to H\to V^*$, the map $H\to V^*$ is (ignoring complex conjugation for this discussion) the adjoint of the map $V\to H$, using self-duality (ignoring complex conjugation) of $H$. That is, the diagram really is $V\to H\approx H^*\to V^*$.

Also, the Riesz-Frechet theorem that gives an isom (ignoring conjugation...) $H\approx H^*$ does *not* behave as one might have thought! Namely, a continuous Hilbert-space map $V\to W$ and adjoint $W^*\to V^*$ does *not* make a commuting square with the Riesz-Frechet isomorphisms $V\approx V^*$ and $W\approx W^*$.

(Small wonder then that the Gelfand-Hilbert inclusion $V\to V^*$ is *not* the Riesz-Fischer map...)